# Confirm password field recommendation

Tags: feature-request, user-interface

When creating a new Stack Overflow account there was not a confirm field for the password, which is a good practice.

After first comments, I have to say the following:

- I agree that it is debatable
- To be more clear, when I signed up there were not second password field, show password option or something similar to be sure that password is correct typed. It is the first time when you choose the password, it's not about forgetting password or mistype login or recover it. In fact I suggest a simple verification, no matter how
  it is done, to be sure of what you entered. I haven't notice one.

Comment: The good practice is challenged: https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/20953/why-should-we-ask-the-password-twice-during-registration but if you would say *it is common practice* we could agree on that.

Comment: More and more users use automatically generated passwords, making the confirm field unnecessary.

Comment: "*In fact I suggest a simple verification, no matter how it is done, to be sure of what you entered. I haven't notice one.*" 1. type your password in some sort of plain text thing (e.g., notepad) 2. Verify it is correct. 3. Paste it in the password field.  **OR** some browsers allow you to reveal the password field. 1. Type your password 2. Reveal to check if it is correct.

Comment: @Mast - or an OAuth2 flow with their provider of choice which is passwordless (in support of the point that the confirmation field is an outdated practice).

Comment: I was just asking about that field, but voting down heavily because the question is obsolete and is not with the trend, as the vote seems, doesn't help anybody. However comments are welcome and everybody is free to vote as they like.

Comment: I'm talking about signing up for the first time (new account), which is done once, not sign in (login) after that.

Answer (score 7):

There's no need for a confirmation field for an account that doesn't involve any identity verification other than a working email address. If you mistype the password when you set it, you just have to use the "forgot password" process to correct it to what you want it to be.

If the site had a more involved process for resetting a password, then confirmation might be desirable, but as it is the confirmation is just annoying (especially for those of us that use a password vault and generated passwords).

Comment: Partial true. But signing up with Google, Facebook or other account means much more behind the scene.